# Configure Nginx as Reverse Proxy for Nodejs App on Jelastic

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, jelastic

I've tried using standard nginx and nodejs configurations following many documentation, but unlike other tutorials there are several files that don't appear in many of the tutorials using Jelastic Paas or additional files such as `nginx-jelastic.conf`. Additionally the Jelastic documentation doesn't seem to cover this in a single page, information seems wide spread and unclear.

What I found so far in the Jelastic official documentation:
https://docs.jelastic.com/nginx-balancer-config/

Unofficial documentation:
https://guillermo.at/jelastic-react

Still seems unclear, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The way configuration files are included in Nginx (or any other webserver) is a bit tricky in Jelastic.

The default configuration used will be /etc/nginx/nginx.conf I which you can see at bottom file nginx-jelastic.conf is included. You can find all relative settings here like your upstream or if you want to divert traffic to different upstream port etc.

You can remove this file reference from /etc/nginx/nginx.conf so it will not be parsed after next service reboot/node reboot

For SSL configuration refer to /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf. You can see SSL related settings here.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring nginx in a Jelastic balancer doesn't differ from setting up nginx balancer on a regular host.

By default, all main settings of the nginx balancer are placed in one file "nginx-jelastic.conf" and it is included in the general nginx configuration using the "include" directive in the main configuration file "nginx.conf". So, depending on the changes you've done, you can make your configuration changes in the file "nginx-jelastic.conf" and restart or reload the service itself after.

We are constantly working on improving our documentation, and try to cover the most frequently used cases, though not all cases can be covered.